# Python socket client always sending message

Tags: python, sockets

So I have this server file which is ok, always is up for connections, after sending a message from the client, client connection closes. I want the client to be up again for sending a message (get input again). I don't want to start the client again (in my case it's odev1.py)

```
# server.py
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen()

    while True:
        print('waiting for a connection')
        connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        try:
            print(f'{client_address[0]} has entered the chat\n')

            while True:
                data = connection.recv(1024)
                print(f'{client_address[0]} - {str(data, encoding="utf-8")}')
                if data:
                    print('sending data back to the client')
                    connection.sendall(data)
                else:
                    print('no data from', client_address[0])
                    break

        finally:
            print("Closing current connection")
            connection.close()
```

this is my client ->

```
# client.py
import sys
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 65432

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error as e:
    print("Error creating socket: %s" % e)
    sys.exit(1)
# Second try-except block -- connect to given host/port

try:
    s.connect((host, port))
except socket.gaierror as e:
    print("Address-related error connecting to server: %s" % e)
    sys.exit(1)
except socket.error as e:
    print("Connection error: %s" % e)
    sys.exit(1)
# Third try-except block -- sending data
try:
    # NOTE: I want it to take input again
    # Send data
    message = input('write something: ')
    s.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))
    print('sending {!r}'.format(message))

    # Look for the response
    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)

    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        amount_received += len(data)
        print('received {!r}'.format(data))

finally:
    print('closing socket')
    s.close()
```

this is how it looks right now:

[image]

Comment: Put last `try ... finally` block into eternal loop.

Comment: @OlvinRoght yeah tried that, it's giving me OSError: Bad file descriptor --- on 
```
s.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))
``` line after the input

Comment: Okay, I thought it's obvious. Correct answer: put last `try..finally` block into eternal loop missing last line.

Comment: Oh, yeah that fixed it, but I didn't exactly get it, could you elaborate please? also put it as an answer I can mark it as solved.

Comment: I doubt that I can explain better than [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close). `Once socket are closed, all future operations on the socket object will fail.`

Comment: I understood it after one minute or so. thanks for that.